# Reenviar tras confirmar cambios con una alerta en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Mi intención es que al pulsar sobre un botón, aparezca una alerta con la opción Confirmar o Cancelar, y que en caso de Confirmar, se realice el proceso de reenvío como si no tuviera la etiqueta `onclick`. Tengo el siguiente código escrito en un jsp:

```
    <spring:url value="/vendedores/eliminarArticulo/{articuloId}" var="eliminarArticuloUrl">
        <spring:param name="articuloId" value="${articulo.id}"/>
    </spring:url>
    
    <a href="${fn:escapeXml(eliminarArticuloUrl)}">
        <button onclick="alerta()" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Dar de baja</button>
    </a>
```

Y la función en JavaScript:

```
function alerta() {
    var opcion = confirm("¿Seguro que desea dar de baja el artículo?");
    if (opcion) {
    
    }
}
```

La pregunta es, qué debería poner en el `if` para que al Aceptar directamente hiciera la función del `button`, es decir, si Acepta directamente se llama al `href` que en este caso sería `/vendedores/eliminarArticulo/{articuloId}` , siendo articuloId un parámetro que se coge de una variable que recibe la página.

Comment: Supongamos que tienes un `form` los datos a enviar están en sus elementos. Basta con que reasignes el atributo **action="url"** a la dirección que necesitas y disparas el evento submit desde el método.

Comment: No tengo ningún `form`, solo necesito la id del artículo por lo que la envío como parámetro al controlador en la URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que pretendes es que, en caso de confirmación por parte del usuario, el botón tenga el comportamiento por defecto, no tienes más que devolver al evento onclick el valor devuelto por prompt:

```
 <a href="${fn:escapeXml(eliminarArticuloUrl)}">
    <button onclick="return alerta()" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Dar de baja</button>
</a>

function alerta() {
  var opcion = confirm("¿Seguro que desea dar de baja el artículo?");
  return opcion;
}
```

Comment: La idea es que al Aceptar me envíe a la url que aparece en la etiqueta de spring, y que necesita del parámetro id del artículo. ¿Funcionaría lo que me dices en este caso?

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta. En realidad si lo único que quieres es que si confirma el botón ejecute su comportamiento por defecto no tienes más que devolver al evento onclik el valor devuelto por el prompt.